# Drop columns of type PeriodIndex based on year

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe having columns as quarters (PeriodIndex) - eg. 2010q1, 2010q2.
Also, there are multiple columns with same name as I have converted monthly data to quaterly data. I want to have columns say from 2011q1 and onwards(drop columns corresponding to 2010q4 and less).
I am trying following code:

```
df.columns = df.to_datetime(df.columns).to_period('Q')
df = df[(df.columns[df.columns.year >= 2011])]
```

But now the columns are repeating three times, quaterwise like: 
2011q1  2011q1  2011q1  2011q1  2011q1  2011q1  2011q1  2011q1  2011q1  2011q2
Expected output columns were 2011q1 2011q1  2011q1  2011q2  2011q2  2011q2  2011q3  2011q3 2011q3 2012q1..

How come this is happening and what would be the best way to filter out dateTime index columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), because filter column names:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.year >= 2011]
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But why `df = df[(df.columns[df.columns.year >= 2011])] ` doesn't work as expected? Why it indroduces extra columns?

Comment: @ggaurav - I think problem is filtered columns are not unique, so maybe need `df = df[(df.columns[df.columns.year >= 2011]).unique()]`

Comment: You got it correct. But your suggested solution is the one which is the better way to go. Thanks!